# Ultramarine blue colour absorbing agent

Tags: color, catalysis

> Ultramarine blue ($\ce{Na2Al2SiO8 + Na2S}$, a sulfide-silicate complex containing sodium and aluminium) is insoluble when mixed in water and gives a blue color appearance to the water solution.
>
> Which chemical (from my understanding, it should be acid) can be used to make the blue color disappear in water (absorb the coloring agent)?

Possibly $\ce{H2SO4}$ will absorb the sodium, releasing $\ce{H2S}$. I want to understand basically

- What is the coloring agent (is it sodium only)
- Which chemicals can I think about to remove the color (absorption of coloring agents)

Comment: No single component of ultramarine blue gives its blue color. The whole chemical by itself is blue. The sodium itself is not blue. Nor does $\ce{H2SO4}$ "absorb" the blue color. It just reacts with ultramarine blue to form new compounds which are not blue. You make it sound like a physical change where in fact it is a chemical change.

Comment: Thanks.Rephrasing - Will H2SO4 make the blue disappear. I just want experts opinion before actually trying it in the lab

Comment: "[Dilute $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{HNO3}$, and $\ce{H2SO4}$ rapidly destroy the blue color, producing hydrogen sulfide ($\ce{H2S}$) in the process.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultramarine)", so yes.